# How to create paper used notation in Latex?

Tags: latex

How to use Latex to create a notation style like this image. or any other suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: This is not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It should have been asked on [tex.sx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). And you are clearly not showing any effort in providing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Rendered Latex Snippet]

```
\documentclass{article}

% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112576/math-mode-in-tabular-without-having-to-use-everywhere
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Typing rules for F$_1$}

\begin{tabular}{LLL}
\hline
\text{\footnotesize(Env $\varnothing$)} & 
\text{\footnotesize(Env $x$)}\\

\frac{}{\varnothing \vdash \diamond} & 
\frac{E \vdash A \quad x \notin dom(E)}{E, x:A \vdash \diamond} \\

&&\\

\text{\footnotesize(Type Const} & 
\text{\footnotesize(Type Arrow)}\\

\frac{E \vdash \diamond}{E \vdash K} & 
\frac{E \vdash A \quad E \vdash B}{E \vdash A \rightarrow B} \\

&&\\

\text{\footnotesize(Val $x$)} & 
\text{\footnotesize(Val Fun)} & 
\text{\footnotesize(Val Appl)} \\

\frac{E\vdash \diamond}{E \vdash x :E(x)} & 
\frac{E,x:A\vdash b:B}{E \vdash \lambda(x:A)b :A \rightarrow B} &
\frac{E \vdash b:A \rightarrow B \quad E \vdash a : A}{E \vdash b(a) : B} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```